# Visualizar nombre en component.html Angular

Tags: angular

Buenas Quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy creando gráficos dinámicos con la librería **highcharts** Consumiendo este servicio: https://api.myjson.com/bins/dd3pa

Código: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqfzez?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

**grafico.component.ts**

En mi **OnInit**

```
  export class MoraGraficoComponent implements OnInit {
    DataGraficos: any[]=[];
    constructor(private MoraGrafico:MoraGrafico) { }

      ngOnInit() {

      }
public getResult(data):void{
    if(data.action==1){
      if(this.aux!==data.qtoken){
        this.DataGraficos=[];
        this.aux=data.qtoken;
        this.getRenderGraphic(data);
      }
    }
  }

private getRenderGraphic(data):void{
    console.log(data.qtoken);
    this.loading=true;
    this.MoraGrafico.getLoadGraphic(data.qtoken)
    .subscribe((DataG)=>{
      this.LoadGraphic(DataG);
      this.loading=false;

    })
  }
    LoadGraphic(data) {

        this.DataGraficos=[];
        for(var i=1;i<=data.filter(c=>c['0']=='-1').map(c=>c[2]);i++)
        {
          jQuery(data.filter(c=>c['0']==i).map(c=>c[2])).highcharts({
            xAxis: {
              categories: data.filter(c=>c['0']==i).map(c=>c[3]),
              crosshair: true
            },
            yAxis: {
              title: {
                text: 'En miles',
                style: {
                  fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
              },
            },
            chart: {
              borderColor: "#164D90",
              borderWidth: 2,
              height: 300,
              type: 'line'
            },
            legend: {
                symbolRadius: 0
            },
            title: {
              text: '<b>'+data.filter(c=>c['0']==i).map(c=>c[2]).pop()+'</b>',
              style: {
                color: '#164D90',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
              }
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true
            },
          subtitle: {
            useHTML: true,
            text: '<table>'+
                  '<tr style="color:green"><td>Brecha: </td><td style="text-align: right"><b>' + data.filter(c=>c['0']==i).map(c=>c[6]).pop() + '</b></td></tr>'+
                  '</table>',
            align: 'right'
          },
            credits: {
              enabled: false
            },
          series: [{
            color: '#0191CE',
            type: 'line',
            name: "TAM Inversion",
            data: data.filter(c=>c['0']==i).map(c=>c[4]),
          },{
            color: 'green',
            type: 'line',
            name: "TAM Stock de Mora Real Neta",
            data: data.filter(c=>c['0']==i).map(c=>c[5]),
          }]
          });

          this.DataGraficos.push(data.filter(c=>c['0']==i).map(c=>c[2])[0]);
          console.log(this.DataGraficos);
        }
    }

}
```

**En mi grafico.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6" *ngFor="let graficos of DataGraficos"  [id]="graficos"><br>
            </div>  
</div>
```

**En mi Grafico.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpHeaders,HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http' 
import {Observable,of, Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError,tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})

export class MoraGrafico{
    //private Url='http://172.20.8.68:8080/cores2/strategos_rmda/ppto-res'
    //private Url = 'https://stg.confianza.pe:9853/cores2/strategos_rmda/ppto-res';
    private Url = 'http://localhost:8080/strategos_rmda/brecha-mora';
    private atoken=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUserDomain'))["token"];
    constructor(private http:HttpClient){
    }

    getLoadGraphic(qtoken: String):Observable<String[]>{

       return this.http.get<String[]>('https://api.myjson.com/bins/qnthy');

    }
}
```

Cuando le dado el console. me arroja resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de ejecutar me arroja un error : **core.js:15713 ERROR Error: Highcharts error #13**

**Renderizado div no encontrado
Este error ocurre si la opción chart.renderTo está mal configurada para que Highcharts no pueda encontrar el elemento HTML para representar el gráfico.
Si usa una ID de DOM al crear el gráfico, asegúrese de que exista un nodo con la misma ID en algún lugar del DOM.**

[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NO SE VISUALIZA EL GRAFICO**

Comment: En donde estas inicializando Highcharts? no se muestra eso en tu codigo

Comment: @roberto en export class MoraGraficoComponent implements OnInit

Comment: En el codigo no hay nada en el metodo `ngOnInit`. Pero encontre donde estas llamando highcharts, esta dentro de tu metodo `LoadGraphic`. He escrito una respuesta, espero te sea de utiildad, pero no veo donde se llame el metodo `LoadGraphic`

Comment: No entiendo el código: ¿Para qué se usa jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas pasando a JQuery un array de tus ids.
tienes que darle un string como selector.
Actualiza tu codigo en la linea correspondiente por:

```
...
jQuery('#' + data.filter(c=>c['0']==i).map(c=>c[2])[0]).highcharts({
...
```

**Explicacion:**

No estoy seguro de la estructura de `data` pero parece que en el siguiente extracto de tu codigo, estas haciendo obteniendo el id de tus elementos.

```
...
this.DataGraficos.push(data.filter(c=>c['0']==i).map(c=>c[2])[0]);
console.log(this.DataGraficos)
...
```

Los cuales son "FINANCIEARA CONFIANZA" Y "CENTRO", esto resulta en el siguiente html despues de que angular renderiza el componente:

```
<div class="row>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6" id="FINANCIERA CONFIANZA"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6" id="CENTRO"><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

y lo que quires hacer es llamar highchart en cada uno de estos elementos de la siguiente manera:

```
jQuery('#FINANCIERA CONFIANZA').highcharts({});
jQuery('#CENTRO').highcharts({});
```

pero lo que realmente esta haciendo tu codigo es lo siguiente

```
jQuery(['FINANCIERA CONFIANZA', 'OTRO VALOR']).highcharts({});
jQuery(['CENTRO', 'OTRO VALOR']).highcharts({});
```

**ngOnInit no ejecuta nada:**

> Recomiendo que implementes **[AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)** para garantizar que tu codigo se ejecuta despues de renderizar el componente.

En el siguiente extracto de tu codigo no estas llamando nada en el metodo `ngOnInit`:

```
...
ngOnInit() {

}

public getResult(data):void{
  if(data.action==1){
    if(this.aux!==data.qtoken){
      this.DataGraficos=[];
      this.aux=data.qtoken;
      this.getRenderGraphic(data);
    }
  }
}
...
```

llama tu funcion `getResult` dentro como se muestra a continuacion:

```
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.getResult(this.data);
}
...
```

> No tengo idea de donde esta `data`, o si esta en tu codigo, pero deberias llamar el metodo para que se ejecute tu funcion, en ningun lado veo que la ejecutes.

Comment: correcto ahora si aparece en el ID pero ya no se visualiza los graficos

Comment: como realizaria para que el highchart llame jQuery('#FINANCIERA CONFIANZA').highcharts({});

Comment: yo en mi onInit puse en duro y si funciono. pero yo quisiera que se haga dinamicamente obtener el id 
DataGraficos=["FINANCIERA CONFIANZA","CENTRO","LIMA ORIENTE","NORTE","NOR ANDINO","SUR","CENTRO 1","CENTRO 2","CENTRO 3"];

Comment: he actualizado mi pregunta

Comment: Te recuerdo que no conzco la estructura de `data` si me muestras un ejemplo de este array, te puedo ayudar mejor. otra cosa, no estas llamando nada en ngOnInit voy a actualizar mi respuesta.

Comment: esta esta es la estructura de la data: https://api.myjson.com/bins/dd3pa

Comment: vamos a un chat

Comment: por favor vamos  a un chat para que orientes bro

Comment: he intentado de todo y nada

Comment: desde ayer he estado intentado me amanecido pero nada hermano

Comment: mandame el link del chat

Comment: como se abre un chat contigo

Comment: api.myjson.com/bins/dd3pa

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/101331/angular?tab=general